# Adding a Maven dependency (XML) on a Android Studio project

Tags: maven, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/yogthos/json-to-pdf) Java library in my Android app. From the documentation, I have to put compile "json-to-pdf:json-to-pdf:0.7.5" in my build.grade dependencies. When I try to sync the project, I get an error:

> Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: json-to-pdf:json-to-pdf:0.7.5

I [asked the owner](https://github.com/yogthos/json-to-pdf/issues/11), but he does not know how to fix it. I think I have to add the following Maven dependencies in build.grade too:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>clojars.org</id>
    <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

But I dont't know how to do that.

Here is my settings so far:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    //mavenCentral() I tried that but doesn't work
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    ...
    compile 'json-to-pdf:json-to-pdf:0.7.5' // Doesn't work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the clojars Maven repository in your build.gradle.

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://clojars.org/repo'
    }
}
```

The author of this library should probably add this to the GitHub readme.

**Update:** I responded to the GitHub issue with the appropriate Gradle snippet that should be added to the docs.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I already tried that but I'm getting this error:
"Error:Failed to notify project evaluation listener."

Comment: That sounds like a completely unrelated problem. I'd try running your build from the command line to see if you get a better error.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I don't know if it's an unrelated error, because if I comment the "compile" line, the sync works properly

Comment: Your error can be fixed by changing to. 0.7.7 but you will run into an issue where the apk will fail to build. The library has a dependency on an old Java library whose class file format seems to not be supported. Quick fix is compile the project your self but Am stuck as I don't know how to compile cloja based Projects